# RTK Query createApi() endpoints not showing up as hooks in Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Trying a simple base query with RTK Query and after defining my api with `createApi()`, Typescript is giving me error when I try to destructure the api to get my hooks.

I then copied pasted the pokemon example code from the docs and even with that, it's saying the hook doesn't exist.

Clearly I'm missing something.

Here's the code, [pulled right from the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview#create-an-api-slice) but with a string return type:

```
export const pokemonApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'pokemonApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/' }),
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
      getPokemonByName: builder.query<string, string>({
        query: (name) => `pokemon/${name}`,
      }),
    }),
})
  
export const { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } = pokemonApi;
```

That `useGetPokemonByNameQuery` is what shows the error:

```
Property 'useGetPokemonByNameQuery' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, { getPokemonByName: QueryDefinition<...>; }, "pokemonApi", never, unique symbol>'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*@reduxjs/toolkit: 1.9.5*

From the [/rtk-query/api/created-api/overview#react-hooks](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/overview#react-hooks) doc:

> The core RTK Query createApi method is UI-agnostic, in the same way that the Redux core library and Redux Toolkit are UI-agnostic. They are all plain JS logic that can be used anywhere.

> However, RTK Query also provides the ability to auto-generate React hooks for each of your endpoints. Since this specifically depends on React itself, RTK Query provides an alternate entry point that exposes a customized version of createApi that includes that functionality

> If you have used the React-specific version of createApi, the generated Api slice structure will also contain a set of React hooks.

> The same hooks are also added to the Api object itself, and given auto-generated names based on the endpoint name and query/mutation type.

Make sure the `createApi` function import from the below path:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
```

NOT:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';
```

The full example can be found [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/v1.9.5/examples/query/react/basic/src/services/pokemon.ts)

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much for that. I need to slow down and read the docs more carefully.

Comment: Why didn't I read the documentation myself? Losing the habit sadly. Thank you very much Lin.